# How to convert a pandas dataframe column to numeric when certain cells contain a letter?

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently trying to find the sum of row containing the SAT scores. The scores are classified as string values so when I add them I get something like 355222333 when I'm supposed to add 355 + 222 + 333. And I can't convert these rows into ints because some rows contain the value "s" I get a value error "unable to parse string "s"".
Here's a sample of the dataframe;

[image: As you can see there are s values for some rows.]

I've tried using this code (I used merge to merge another dataframe that is not used in this code.):
`Merged = pd.merge(SAT, AP, on=['DBN', 'SCHOOL NAME']) Merged["SAT Critical Reading Avg. Score"] = pd.to_numeric(Merged["SAT Critical Reading Avg. Score"]) Merged['SAT Math Avg. Score'] = pd.to_numeric(Merged['SAT Math Avg. Score']) Merged['SAT Writing Avg. Score'] = pd.to_numeric(Merged['SAT Writing Avg. Score']) Total = Merged['SAT Critical Reading Avg. Score'] + Merged['SAT Math Avg. Score'] + Merged['SAT Writing Avg. Score'] Merged['Total SAT SCORE'] = Total Merged.head(50)`

Is there a way for me to ignore these values or just remove the row that contains them? I hope this isn't a stupid question, I haven't touched python in years. Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: One option: You can use `errors='coerce'`  per [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) in which "invalid parsing will be set as NaN"

Comment: Ah thank you! It was there all along... Being new to pandas and all, I didn't realize. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Happy to help! It's always worth reading through the documentation on the functions you're using to see what options are available